# Matplotlib: How to change the color of a LineCollection according to its coordinates?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

Consider the folowing plot:

[image]

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (14, 6))
ax.set_facecolor('k')
ax.set_xlim(0, 100)
ax.set_ylim(0, 100)

xs = np.arange(60, 70)          # xs = np.linspace(60, 70, 100)
ys = np.arange(0, 100, .5)      # ys = np.linspace(0, 100, 100)

v = [[[x, y] for x in xs] for y in ys]

lines = LineCollection(v, linewidth = 1, cmap = plt.cm.Greys_r)
lines.set_array(xs)
ax.add_collection(lines)
```

How can I change the color of the lines according to their `x` coordinates (horizontally)  so as to create a "shading" effect like this:

[image]

Here, the greater `x` is, the "whiter" the `LineCollection` is.

Following this reasoning, I thought that specifying `lines.set_array(xs)` would do the trick but as you can see in my plot the color gradation is still following the y axis. Strangely the pattern is repeating itself, from black to white (every 5) over and over (up to 100).

I think (not sure at all) the problem lies in the `v` variable that contains the coordinates. The concatenation of `x` and `y` might be improper.

Comment: something like the top plot here maybe: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/multicolored_line.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-multicolored-line-py

Comment: I've been trying this one but colors are changing according to the y axis, I can't figure why.

Comment: update your question with your latest attempt

Comment: I give up, spent hours on this. Changing the color of a LineSegment vertically is impossible.

Comment: The questions asks about doing it horizontally, not vertically. Both options are possible. As has been pointed out in a previous comment, you may update your question with a clear problem description including the attempted solution. I'm sure there is an easy fix to any problem you have with the code.

Comment: My bad, I meant horizontally. I updated the question yesterday as requested. The description is now edited. I can't report every attempt made, there's too many but what you can see in the "best" option I could find so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shape of the list `v` you supply to the `LineCollection` is indeed not suitable to create a gradient of the desired direction. This is because each line in a LineCollection can only have single color. Here the lines range from x=60 to x=70 and each of those lines has one color.

What you need to do instead is to create a line collection where each line is devided into several segments, each of which can then have its own color.

To this end an array of dimensions `(n, m, l)`, where `n` is the number of segments, `m` is the number of points per segment, and `l` is the dimension (2D, hence `l=2`) needs to be used.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (14, 6))
ax.set_facecolor('k')
ax.set_xlim(0, 100)
ax.set_ylim(0, 100)

xs = np.linspace(60, 70, 100)
ys = np.linspace(0, 100, 100)


X,Y = np.meshgrid(xs,ys)
s = X.shape
segs = np.empty(((s[0])*(s[1]-1),2,2))
segs[:,0,0] = X[:,:-1].flatten()
segs[:,1,0] = X[:,1:].flatten()
segs[:,0,1] = Y[:,:-1].flatten()
segs[:,1,1] = Y[:,1:].flatten()

lines = LineCollection(segs, linewidth = 1, cmap = plt.cm.Greys_r)
lines.set_array(X[:,:-1].flatten())
ax.add_collection(lines)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is well explained. Thank you.